# Custom XML Serialization with x:

Tags: c#, .net, xml, file

I am trying to generate/serialize an XML file with custom tag in C# and even though I have tried multiple solutions, I have not been able to come up with a valid solution, I will appreciate any contribution. The file should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <x:Todo>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <x:UserId>27</UserId>
 </Todo>
```

The issue is I have no idea how to add **x:** to the tag in specifics nodes.

Thank in advance for all your contributions.
Me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define namespace and use it, here is an example (from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializernamespaces?view=net-5.0)):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Run
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Run test = new Run();
        test.SerializeObject("XmlNamespaces.xml");
    }

    public void SerializeObject(string filename)
    {
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Book));
        // Writing a file requires a TextWriter.
        TextWriter t = new StreamWriter(filename);

        /* Create an XmlSerializerNamespaces object and add two
        prefix-namespace pairs. */
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("x", "http://www.cpandl.com");

        // Create a Book instance.
        Book b = new Book();
        b.TITLE = "A Book Title";
        s.Serialize(t, b, ns);
        t.Close();
    }
}

[XmlType(Namespace = "http://www.cpandl.com")]
public class Book
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://www.cpandl.com")]
    public string TITLE;
}
```